# Laravel 5.8 access error messageBag for array validation

Tags: laravel-5.8

I validate an 2d array and when there are validator failures, the `validator->errors()` contains:

```
MessageBag {#1010 ▼
  #messages: array:8 [▼
    "1.0" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The 1.0 does not match the format d/m/Y."
    ]
    "2.0" => array:1 [▶]
    "1.1" => array:1 [▶]
    "2.1" => array:1 [▶]
    "1.2" => array:1 [▶]
    "2.2" => array:1 [▶]
    "1.4" => array:1 [▶]
    "2.4" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Now I can access all errors like this:

```
foreach ($errors->all() as $error) {

}
```

This places the message in `$error = "The 1.0 does not match the format d/m/Y.";`

How do I access the "1.0" key?

Comment: do you mean how to get the first error message, please?

Comment: No, I want to access the key to each error, the "1.0", "1.1" etc

Comment: check my answer, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. `$key` will contain the "1.0", and $error the message.

```
   foreach ($errors->getMessages() as $key => $error) {


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `MessageBag`, there is a method `keys()` with it you get all `MessageBag` keys, for more information about the methods that you can use with the `MessageBag` class, please check [MessageBag laravel api doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html)